# DB Design Prevent Invalid third value

Tags: database, foreign-keys

Say I have 2 items:

- Powder (measured in g)
- Juice (measured in ml)

So naturally there's a table `PRODUCT (product_id, product_name)`, I have

```
product_id,product_name
1,powder
2,juice
```

Now, the juice can be stored in 1 litre bottles and 250ml bottles, while the powder could be in 100g sachets or 500g sachets. Creating a table `BASE_UNIT(bunit_id, bunit_name)`, I have

```
bunit_id, bunit_name
1,ml
2,g
```

and `UNIT(unit_id,unit_name,unit_multiplier,bunit_fk)` with

```
unit_id,unit_name,unit_multiplier,bunit_fk
1,1l bottle,1000,1
2,250ml bottle,250,1
3,100g sachet,100,2
4,500g sachet,500,2
```

How can I use this structure (in 3NF form) to enforce such that the juice can only be stored in `ml`, while being able to add more `BASE_UNIT`, say `ea`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a `unit_id` column to the product table, make it a foreign key to the `base_unit` table - that will ensure a one-to-many relationship between the product and the base unit. If you have a product that can be measured in more than one unit, you'll need a bridge table to create a many-to-many relationship between `product` and `base_unit`.